With Photoshop how can I match the colors of two similar image?
So I have a high res image of an artwork but I prefer the colors of a low res version of the same image. How can I match the colors of the low res version onto the high res version?
The original low res image:

The high res image with "bad" colors:


Image -> Adjustments -> Match Color...?

@joojaa nah I already tried it and the white becomes pink/purple.

Paste the low res version as a new top layer to the high res version. Move and stretch the inserted layer so that the woods and water details are as coincident as possible. Reduce the top layer opacity temporarily to see both layers in the same time. You cannot get it pixel perfect because the low res version becomes blurry, but do your best. If the images are different camera shots you may need even to apply distortions such as warp.
Change the blending mode of the top layer to "Color" and that's it. In the next image the effect is limited to 50% of the image width by inserting a layer mask

This doesn't add any glare nor other defects that clearly exist in your low res version, but have the wanted color.
Why this works? Because white and black cannot be colored by blending mode color and generally human vision recognizes forms more as brightness variations. Color borders can be a little blurry.
